# Something is wrong with cocoapods

Tags: ios, ruby, rvm, cocoapods

Have added a new pod file to the new project, then terminal -> pod install.... and:

```
---------------------------------------------
Error loading the plugin with path `/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/cocoapods-stats-0.6.0/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb`.

LoadError - cannot load such file -- /Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/cocoapods-stats-0.6.0/lib/cocoapods_plugin.rb
/Users/rudra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:106:in `safe_require'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:32:in `block in load_plugins'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `each'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command/plugin_manager.rb:31:in `load_plugins'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:304:in `block in run'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `each'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:48:in `run'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/cocoapods-0.38.2/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/rudra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
---------------------------------------------

0.38.2
```

I have already tried to reinstall pods, ruby, rvm and no luck yet. A week ago everything was fine, nothing was installed or updated.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue right now. Any luck finding a solution?

Comment: Reinstall rvm, ruby, pods and update all gems. Then turn off your mac and go to sleep. Next day it should work.